# Safari not calling Promise.then in twitter createWidget

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, safari, promise

I'm using Twitter's `twttr.widgets.createTweet` to render a list of tweets to the page, by ID (`initialTweets` is a json of Tweet IDs).

```
    var initialTweets = <?php echo json_encode($tweets); ?>;
    $(window).load(function(){
        if(initialTweets.length) {
            for(i = 0; i < initialTweets.length; i++) {
                var data = initialTweets[i];
                var newTweet = document.createElement('div');
                twttr.widgets.createTweet(
                    data, newTweet, {}
                ).then(function (el) {
                    $('#tweets').prepend($(el));
                    var tweets = $('#tweets > twitterwidget');
                    console.log('Tweets: ' . tweets.length);
                    if (tweets.length > max) {
                        tweets.eq(max).nextAll().remove();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

This works fine in Chrome 52, but isn't working in Safari - if I add some console logging, it seems that the `.then` function isn't being called. I know that the Tweet element is being created, as I can see the iframes being called in network inspector.

Comment: What if you use error callback? Any relevant message?

Comment: @A.Wolff - or `.catch(` block

Comment: Thanks both. I've just added a `.catch(function(e){ console.log(e); })`, but it's not logging anything. (@A.Wolff is that what you meant?)

Comment: @AdamHopkinson Ya, that was what i meant. And so, are you sure the `then` callback isn't called? Set a console.log in3

Comment: Hmm. I did put in `.then(function (el) { console.log('In promise.then'); }` and got nothing in Safari (worked in Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, hard to say why Safari should be problematic.

Here's something which may just be good for diagnosis or may offer a permanent solution. The idea is to prepend a target div to `#tweets` in advance of calling `twttr.widgets.createTweet()`, offering the possibility of :

- displaying a "loading..." message for each tweet.
- displaying an error message message for each tweet.
- ensuring that the tweets will be displayed in the same order as the original `initialTweets` array, which is not guaranteed in the current code.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var initialTweets = <?php echo json_encode($tweets); ?>,
        $tweets = $('#tweets'),
        loadingMessage = 'loading...';
    initialTweets.forEach(function(tweetID) {
        var $div = $('<div/>').text(loadingMessage).prependTo($tweets); // create and prepend a target div
        return twttr.widgets.createTweet(tweetID, $div.get(0), {}).then(function(el) {
            $(el).unwrap(); // remove the prepended target div, leaving the twitter widget in place
            var $widgets = $tweets.children('twitterwidget');
            if ($widgets.length > max) {
                $widgets.eq(max).nextAll().remove();
            }
        }, function(error) {
            $div.text(error.message); // for testing/diagnosis
            // $div.remove(); // for live environment
            throw error;
        });
    });
});
```